# in python how to access half iterate forloop value outside without if condition

Tags: python, django

i am iterating a large number of list like 100,000 data.

I want to know how much iteration is completed outside of the loop.

I don't want to use if condition. if condition increases execution time.

```
def callme():
    for data in range(100000):
        # i want to return 'data' after every 5 seconds.
        # without if condition
        return data
```

Comment: use generator as here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want a generator with a time delay.

```
import time

def callme():
    for data in range(100000):
        time.sleep(5)
        yield data
```

However, note that you *must* have some sort of execution cost, since *something* must decide when to emit your `data` value.

Answer (score 2):

Use generator as here: [LINK](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
def callme(inputs):
    for data in range(100000):
        # do something such as sleep system for 5 seconds 
        yield (data)

callme_ = callme(inputs)
out = next(callme_)
# out = callme_.next() # this can also be used.
```

Note: yield will return data once its next element is called. You I would recommend to use timer/sleep outside the generator. You can also use scheduler.

Comment: i want data like data = callme()       sleep(2)    get forloop data after 2 second but loop iteration should be continue